# Problem with Video recording after auto focus in Android

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo, android-camera

Im trying to build an app which tries to auto focus the camera before starting the video recording. Directly using `MediaRecorder` does not auto focus the camera. For that i am Using `Camera` and using the callback I can autofocus it. But providing this instance to the `MediaRecorder` gives me a lot of issues. Following is the code im using for recording

```
public boolean startRecording()
{
    try
    {
        mCamera.unlock();

        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);

        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

        CamcorderProfile profile = CamcorderProfile
                .get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW);
        mediaRecorder.setProfile(profile);

        mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(maxDurationInMs);

        File file = new File(outputFile);
        if (file.exists())
            file.delete();
        file = new File(outputFile);

        try
        {
            file.createNewFile();
        }
        catch (IOException e1)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Deepak", "*** first catch ***");
        }


        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(outputFile);
        mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder.getSurface());

        mediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(maxFileSizeInBytes);

        mediaRecorder.prepare();
        mediaRecorder.start();

        return true;
    }
    catch (IllegalStateException e)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

The Camera attributes are as follows:

```
Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
    List<Size> sizeList = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
    parameters.setPreviewFormat(ImageFormat.JPEG);
    parameters
            .setPreviewSize(sizeList.get(0).width, sizeList.get(0).height);
    mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
    mCamera.startPreview();
```

All this is giving me the following error message:

```
    11-22 16:51:25.314: DEBUG/Preview(4052): !!!!!!!!!!111Starting recording!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
11-22 16:51:25.334: ERROR/audio_input(59): unsupported parameter: x-pvmf/media-input-node/cap-config-interface;valtype=key_specific_value
11-22 16:51:25.334: ERROR/audio_input(59): VerifyAndSetParameter failed
11-22 16:51:25.334: ERROR/CameraInput(59): Unsupported parameter(x-pvmf/media-input-node/cap-config-interface;valtype=key_specific_value)
11-22 16:51:25.334: ERROR/CameraInput(59): VerifiyAndSetParameter failed on parameter #0
11-22 16:51:25.344: DEBUG/AuthorDriver(59): setParamVideoEncodingBitrate() 256000
11-22 16:51:25.384: INFO/MediaRecorderJNI(4052): prepare: surface=0x222968 (id=1)
11-22 16:51:25.394: ERROR/PVOMXEncNode(59): PVMFOMXEncNode-Video_M4V::DoPrepare(): Got Component OMX.qcom.video.encoder.mpeg4 handle 
11-22 16:51:25.394: WARN/CameraInput(59): refCount 0
11-22 16:51:25.394: ERROR/VENC_ENC(59): VENC_ERROR update_param_port_def::1643 Frame rate is for input port (refer to OMX IL spec)
11-22 16:51:25.394: ERROR/VENC_ENC(59): VENC_ERROR get_parameter::952 unsupported index 0x700000b
11-22 16:51:25.394: ERROR/VENC_ENC(59): VENC_ERROR set_parameter::2720 unsupported index 0x700000b
11-22 16:51:25.394: ERROR/VENC_ENC(59): VENC_ERROR translate_profile::1015 unsupported profile
11-22 16:51:25.394: ERROR/VENC_ENC(59): Bitrate 256000
11-22 16:51:25.394: ERROR/VENC_ENC(59): VENC_ERROR get_parameter::952 unsupported index 0x6000005
11-22 16:51:25.394: ERROR/VENC_ENC(59): VENC_ERROR set_parameter::2720 unsupported index 0x6000005
11-22 16:51:25.394: ERROR/PVOMXEncNode(59): PVMFOMXEncNode-Audio_AMRNB::DoPrepare(): Got Component OMX.PV.amrencnb handle 
11-22 16:51:25.394: DEBUG/CameraInput(59): Intended mFrameWidth=176, mFrameHeight=144 
11-22 16:51:25.404: DEBUG/CameraInput(59): Actual mFrameWidth=176, mFrameHeight=144 
11-22 16:51:25.404: ERROR/VENC_ENC(59): VENC_ERROR ven_translate_config::428 Invalid mp4 configuration 
11-22 16:51:25.424: INFO/AudioHardwareQSD(59): Routing audio to Speakerphone
11-22 16:51:25.424: DEBUG/AudioHardwareQSD(59): Switching audio device to 
11-22 16:51:25.424: DEBUG/AudioHardwareQSD(59): Speakerphone
11-22 16:51:25.454: ERROR/CameraInput(59): Recording is not ready (iPeer 0x3bc14 iState 2 iWriteState 1 iClockState 0), frame dropped
11-22 16:51:25.494: ERROR/CameraInput(59): Recording is not ready (iPeer 0x3bc14 iState 2 iWriteState 1 iClockState 0), frame dropped
11-22 16:51:25.534: ERROR/CameraInput(59): Recording is not ready (iPeer 0x3bc14 iState 2 iWriteState 1 iClockState 0), frame dropped
11-22 16:51:25.554: INFO/AudioHardwareQSD(59): AudioHardware PCM record is going to standby.
11-22 16:51:25.554: INFO/AudioHardwareQSD(59): Routing audio to Speakerphone
11-22 16:51:25.564: INFO/AudioHardwareQSD(59): do input routing device 800000
11-22 16:51:25.564: INFO/AudioHardwareQSD(59): Routing audio to Speakerphone with back mic
11-22 16:51:25.564: ERROR/CameraInput(59): Recording is not ready (iPeer 0x3bc14 iState 2 iWriteState 1 iClockState 0), frame dropped
11-22 16:51:25.574: WARN/AudioFlinger(59): write blocked for 143 msecs, 52 delayed writes, thread 0xd7a8
11-22 16:51:25.604: ERROR/CameraInput(59): Recording is not ready (iPeer 0x3bc14 iState 2 iWriteState 1 iClockState 0), frame dropped
11-22 16:51:25.644: ERROR/CameraInput(59): Recording is not ready (iPeer 0x3bc14 iState 2 iWriteState 1 iClockState 0), frame dropped
11-22 16:51:25.684: ERROR/CameraInput(59): Recording is not ready (iPeer 0x3bc14 iState 2 iWriteState 1 iClockState 0), frame dropped
11-22 16:51:25.754: DEBUG/AudioHardwareQSD(59): Switching audio device to 
11-22 16:51:25.754: DEBUG/AudioHardwareQSD(59): Speakerphone
11-22 16:51:25.764: ERROR/CameraInput(59): Recording is not ready (iPeer 0x3bc14 iState 2 iWriteState 1 iClockState 0), frame dropped
11-22 16:51:25.814: ERROR/CameraInput(59): Recording is not ready (iPeer 0x3bc14 iState 2 iWriteState 1 iClockState 0), frame dropped
11-22 16:51:25.844: ERROR/CameraInput(59): Recording is not ready (iPeer 0x3bc14 iState 2 iWriteState 1 iClockState 0), frame dropped
11-22 16:51:25.884: ERROR/CameraInput(59): Recording is not ready (iPeer 0x3bc14 iState 2 iWriteState 1 iClockState 0), frame dropped
11-22 16:51:25.924: ERROR/CameraInput(59): Recording is not ready (iPeer 0x3bc14 iState 2 iWriteState 1 iClockState 0), frame dropped
11-22 16:51:25.964: ERROR/CameraInput(59): Recording is not ready (iPeer 0x3bc14 iState 2 iWriteState 1 iClockState 0), frame dropped
11-22 16:51:26.004: ERROR/CameraInput(59): Recording is not ready (iPeer 0x3bc14 iState 2 iWriteState 1 iClockState 0), frame dropped
11-22 16:51:26.044: ERROR/CameraInput(59): Recording is not ready (iPeer 0x3bc14 iState 2 iWriteState 1 iClockState 0), frame dropped
11-22 16:51:28.824: INFO/AudioHardwareQSD(59): AudioHardware pcm playback is going to standby.
11-22 16:51:31.324: DEBUG/Preview(4052): !!!!!!!!!!Stoping recording!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

This creates a file on the specified location which is totally obscured, just a bunch of green horizontal lines.

All permission are placed. Using Android 2.2. Tried the exact code as [this](http://integratingstuff.com/2010/10/18/writing-code-that-captures-videos-on-android/) but still got similar `VENC_ERROR`

Answer (score 12):

You need to stop the preview prior to unlocking the camera

```
mCamera.stopPreview();

mCamera.unlock();
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me on the HTC Desire but unfortunately not on the Samsung S2.

Comment: Fixed my green garbled video issue on S4 that wasn't happening on S3 of Nexus 5.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Fixed video corruption issue on Motorola Defy.