# Android MediaRecorder produces corrupt video with green lines

Tags: java, android, video, mediarecorder

I'm trying to add video recording capability to my app using MediaRecorder in Android, but the resulting video looks corrupt with green lines (audio is fine).  The following code is what I use to initialize the MediaRecorder object:

```
mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
mCamera.unlock();
mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);
mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(Utility.CAPTURE_VIDEO_FILENAME);
mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H263);
mMediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(60000);
mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(20);
mMediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(5000000);
mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(352, 288);
mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mPreview.mHolder.getSurface());
mMediaRecorder.prepare();
mMediaRecorder.start();
```

I've already looked at the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889579/android-camera-capture-produces-green-and-blocky-video) and [here](http://integratingstuff.com/2010/10/18/writing-code-that-captures-videos-on-android/), but they don't seem to help my cause.  I do think, however, that it might have something to do with incorrect video size.  So my question is this: is there any good way to get compatible video sizes when using API level 7?  As far as I can tell I can use CamcorderProfile if I'm in API level 8, but nothing in 7.

Comment: The last answer on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244999/problem-with-video-recording-after-auto-focus-in-android) post did it. You need to call Camera.stopPreview() before Camera.unlock().

Comment: i have similar problem... and not fixing it on 100%. I reading many post's and guys sayd - it's bug . But not on all phones.  Also if setVideoSize(320,240)(320,240  worked on phone.. but when set more than i see green blocky) - it's must fix it too

Answer (score 1):

Video sizes in a device is equal to preview sizes. You have to first check whether video size you setting is available or not. Video sizes in different devices may be diffrent.so,first check available preview sizes using [getSupportedPreviewSizes](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedPreviewSizes%28%29) () and then set video size.if video size is incorrect green lines will come.

Answer (score 1):

You can change these option and see how the qulity varies:

```
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);
```

Following code will anyway record a video for you:

MediaRecorder recorder;

```
private void initRecorder() {

    recorder = new MediaRecorder(); 
        recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);

        if (this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation != Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            recorder.setOrientationHint(90);//plays the video correctly
        }else{
            recorder.setOrientationHint(180);
        }


        recorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/MediaAppVideos/"+randomNum+".mp4");

    }

private void prepareRecorder() {
        recorder.setPreviewDisplay(holder.getSurface());
        try {
            recorder.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try {
            if (recording) {
                recorder.stop();
                recording = false;
            }
            recorder.release();
            // finish();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

    }
```

Comment: Changing the setVideoEncoder to  MPEG_4_SP solved my problem. Thanks @TharakaNirmana

Answer (score 1):

Check your code for the setRecordingHint(true);

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setRecordingHint(boolean)

The setting of this parameter cause this green glitches in the video on few devices.

Answer (score 0):

For me green patches happened only on one device for 1920x1080. For higher or lower resolutions, recorded video is okay. When I set preview size to be same size as video size, I don't see any green strips

Comment: This is not an answer