# MediaRecorder recorded video is scrambled

Tags: android, video, mediarecorder

The approach I've tried to implement is shown below.

It saves the file and the audio is fine, but the video is all greenish lines.

What am I doing wrong?

```java
camera.unlock();
mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
mediaRecorder.setCamera(camera);
mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);

mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);

mediaRecorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/"+ videoName + ".mp4");

mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(240, 240);
mediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(24);
mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());

//mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(10000);
//mediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(10000000);

mediaRecorder.prepare();
mediaRecorder.start();
```

Comment: I removed the `<blink>` tags in your post, and fixed your language specifier comment.  Was there a reason you were trying to get your code block to blink?

Comment: Wasn't his fault, Carth edited that in, check the [edit history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/8068398/revisions). I rejected his edit, though others have approved it in the end.

Comment: @alextsc No, it was there in the original version, just not indented, so the parser and/or browser wasn't displaying them as code. http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/cd5e91c2-2237-4dd6-9296-da9cf64903f2/view-source

Comment: Oh damn, just checked the source. You're right, don't know how I missed that. In this case I owe Carth an apology. I'm sorry, wasn't your fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found my answer at:
[Problem with Video recording after auto focus in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244999/problem-with-video-recording-after-auto-focus-in-android/4980384#4980384)

```
camera.stopPreview();

camera.unlock();

//etc
```

This fixed it.